# Not getting track list of some users in soundcloud api

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, soundcloud

By using below api for getting track list of soundcloud user

Not working example:
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/tycho/tracks.json?client_id=xxxx...

Working example:
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/chk-chk-chk/tracks.json?client_id=xxxx...

This api provides result for some user only

I am not able to get track of all user

Is there anything else that i forgot to do

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Soundcloud API is blocking some requests from some countries for some users.

Answer (score 1):

Users can choose not allowing api calls on their tracks.